# how to get objects from json file?

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file as below

```
{
  "requestData": {
    "username": "admin"
  },
  "eventTime": "2023-12-01T23:50:02.554+0000",
  "observer": {
    "id": "target"
  }
```

I want to get only the below output side by side,O/P

```
"username": "admin","eventTime": "2023-12-01T23:50:02.554+0000"
```

I tried using below but, able to get only one record at a time, how to nest both and get above output

```
cat filename  | jq '.requestData.username'
```

}

Comment: Do you mean `{"username": "admin","eventTime": "2023-12-01T23:50:02.554+0000"}` _with the curly  braces_? Without them, you're asking for output that isn't valid JSON -- which jq _can_ do, but it's extra work.

Comment: Or do you just want to get the key/value pairs into your shell and not care about the exact formatting?

Comment: How about `jq '.requestData + {eventTime}'`? Add the `-c` flag to compact all into one line.

Comment: do you mean linux or unix commnds / scripts  to read the Json file values ?

Comment: @hello all, thanks for your reply: Below o/p should also be fine     ===> "admin", "2023-12-01T23:50:02.554+0000"

Comment: Then how about `jq -r '@json "\(.requestData.username), \(.eventTime)"'`?

Comment: If you just want to pick out the values and keep the object whole, consider: `pick(.requestData.username, .eventTime)`

Answer (score 0):

The following should give you exactly what you want:

```
$ cat filename | jq -r '"\"username\": \"" + .requestData.username + "\", \"eventTime\": \"" + .eventTime + "\""'
"username": "admin", "eventTime": "2023-12-01T23:50:02.554+0000"
```

If you just want the values:

```
$ cat filename | jq -r '"\"" + .requestData.username + "\", \"" + .eventTime + "\""'
"admin", "2023-12-01T23:50:02.554+0000"
```

Or, if you want to use string interpolation as Jeff suggests:

```
$ cat filename | jq -r '"\"username\": \"\(.requestData.username)\", \"eventTime\": \"\(.eventTime)\""'
"username": "admin", "eventTime": "2023-12-01T23:50:02.554+0000"
```

Comment: When building up strings, especially in this case, you'll want to use [string interpolation](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#string-interpolation) to make it a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty, but building an array first, then joining the json-encoded values on colon, followed by a join on comma:

```
jq -r '
[["username", .requestData.username], ["eventTime", .eventTime]]
| map(map(tojson)|join(":"))
| join(",")
'
```

Output:

```
"username":"admin","eventTime":"2023-12-01T23:50:02.554+0000"
```